# ComponentDidCatch not working inside react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-error-boundary

I have this component. Inside `componentDidMount` I created an object and try to throw the error. But the my `componentDidCatch` has not been called instead breaks my page!

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      errorInfo: null
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Catch errors in any child components and re-renders with an error message
    this.setState({
      error,
      errorInfo
    });
    console.log({ error, errorInfo });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const d = {}
    console.log(d.d.d)
  }

  render() {
    console.log("458454545454")
    if (this.state.error) {
      console.log("Error occurred")
    }
    return(<div>dffdfdfdfdfd</div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `static getDerivedStateFromError` if you want to render some UI after catching an error.

Also, [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) not catch an errors thrown in the error boundary itself (that's why I add `FaultyComponent` throwing an actual error).

```js
function FaultyComponent() {
  throw new Error("Test error");

  return <span>Faulty</span>;
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false
    };
  }
  
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {    
    return { hasError: true };  
  }
  
  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.log('componentDidCatch', { error, errorInfo });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <FaultyComponent />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[componentDidCatch](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch)

> This lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a
> descendant component.

`componentDidCatch` doesn't catch errors thrown by the same component.

Comment: Tried this as well. I have did this in a child component and still did not get the `componentDidCatch` called